# Two fancybox in one page issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-easyui

I am using two fancybox at one page and jquery.easing.1.3.js. It conflect with plugins.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7EN5/1/)

```
 $(".enquiry").fancybox({
     type:           'ajax',
     autoDimensions: false,
    'autoSize':     false,
    'height':       'auto'  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7EN5/1/)  is triggering a js error that prevents fancybox from working :

```
TypeError: $(...).tmpl(...).prependTo is not a function
http://royalhome.ae/js/gallery.js
Line 142
```

It seems like the `.tmpl()` method is not being recognized : a bug in the [SKD](http://royalhome.ae/js/jquery.tmpl.min.js) plugin?

If you remove the gallery.js from the fiddle, fancybox works just fine. See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4NtW2/1/)**

Also **notice** I added the fancybox files without `?v=` trailing parameter since it seems jsfiddle won't load them properly with it.

I cannot tell you how to fix your `tmpl` plugin issues but at least you know where to start.